# How to get text in separate TD using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have HTML structure in which one td contains two text. I want wrap second text in another td  and append it after first td like. I have made a function but is not working exactly. here is example [code](http://jsfiddle.net/eHnmC/)

```
//Current html
<tr>
<td>first <a>second</a></td>
</tr>

//expected result
<tr>
<td>first</td>
<td><a>second</a></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var ff= [];
$('a').click(function(){
$('td a').each(function(index){
ff.push($(this).prop('outerHTML'));
$(this).remove();
$('td').eq(index).after().append('<td>'+ff[index]+'</td>')
})})})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append each td's a inside a new td and add after the original td:

```
$('a').click(function(){

        $('td a').each(function(){
            $(this).parent().after('<td></td>');

            $(this).appendTo( $(this).parent().next() );


            });
        });
```

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eHnmC/5/)

or in one line (more confusing, maybe :) ):

```
$('td a').each(function(){
            $(this).appendTo( $(this).parent().after('<td></td>').next() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('td a').each(function(index){
        $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent()).wrap('<td />');
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eHnmC/11/)